# how to extract value from previous soap request and pass to another new request in jmeter?

Tags: web-services, xpath, soap, jmeter

I want to extract previous soap response values and pass it to next request in jmeter,please provide better help and please find my soap request .

soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.clp.eks.com" xmlns:wsf="http://wsform.clp.eks.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:PB_GC_SaveTxn>
         <ser:inputForm>
            <wsf:carddiscount>1.00</wsf:carddiscount>
            <wsf:cardno>69699</wsf:cardno>
            <wsf:cashmemodt>03-06-2017</wsf:cashmemodt>
            <wsf:couponcode></wsf:couponcode>
            <wsf:mcdtls>1001@1.00@1000.00@0.00</wsf:mcdtls>
            <wsf:paymentCardno>CASH-CASH@1000.00</wsf:paymentCardno>
            <wsf:paymentmode>CASH@1000.00</wsf:paymentmode>
            <wsf:no>1</wsf:posno>
            <wsf:rpoint></wsf:rpoint>
            <wsf:code>727</wsf:sitecode>
            <wsf:txnno>31129</wsf:txnno>
         </ser:inputForm>
      </ser:PB_GC_SaveTxn>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now i need to extract Date,Card,Txn no,Store and pass into next request i.e cancel txn request,please provide solution how to use ,i've used xpath extractor but it is not working.

Comment: you want to extract from response? where's the response and the xpath you tried?

Comment: I want to extract from request instead of response and coming to screenshot in case i'm uploading the screenshot it is not displaying the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your response is not valid, to wit:

   ```
   <wsf:no>1</wsf:posno>`
        ^ it should be <wsf:posno>`
   <wsf:code>727</wsf:sitecode>
        ^ it should be <wsf:sitecode>
   ```

   If there is a copy-paste issue it's fine, if your application responds this way - this is a bug. You won't be able to use XPath Extractor in this case, you will need to switch to [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
2. Given you will be able to get correct response (valid XML) use XPath query like:

   ```
   //wsf:cashmemodt | //wsf:cardno| //wsf:txnno
   ```

   to get Date, Card and Txn. I have no idea what "Store" is
3. Here is a demo from XPath Tester mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener (see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about the troubleshooting approach)

   [image: JMeter Xpath Tester Demo]

Comment: I'm not able to see png images

Comment: K i.e Copy paste issue.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,i'm not able to perform as above and receiving error message as "Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: wsf
See log file for further details."

Comment: Where should i use Xpath extractor below request or above the 2nd request,unable to understand

Comment: 1. XPath Extractor should be as a child of the 1st request. 2. Tick `Use Namespaces` box. 3. Provide Reference Name, i.e. `myvar`. 4. The following variables will be generated: `myvar_1=69699`, `myvar_2=03-06-2017` and `myvar_3=31129`. 5. Use them like `${myvar_1}`, `${myvar_2}` etc where required, i.e. in 2nd sampler. 6. See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for more details.